# Alternatives to pg_notify and database triggers for triggering API calls on table updates

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am currently working on a project where I need to make API calls whenever a row is updated in a table. During my research, I came across the built-in PostgreSQL function `pg_notify`, which allows sending notifications to a client. However, I have discovered a few drawbacks with this approach.

One major concern is that notifications can be lost if the client application is not actively listening. Additionally, using `pg_notify` involves utilizing database triggers, which can be expensive and potentially slow down transactions due to their synchronous nature. As the number of inserts grows, I want to avoid any potential database slowdown.

Considering these limitations, I would like to explore alternative approaches or solutions to trigger API calls upon table updates.

Any suggestions for alternative methods or best practices that can help achieve this functionality would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

**Source:**
[Drawbacks of pg_notify](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/remediate-object-change-notifications-from-oracle-to-amazon-aurora-postgresql-or-amazon-rds-for-postgresql/#:%7E:text=A%20benefit%20of%20this%20solution%20is%20that%20pg_notify%20is%20asynchronous,client%20application%20isn%27t%20listening)

Comment: You can use Debezium for this, with or without the usage of Kafka: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/development/engine.html

Comment: You can use a queue table that persistently records the modifications and is filled with a trigger.

Comment: @FrankHeikens If I don't use Kafka, I would need to handle the offsets myself. What is the difference between using pg_notify with Kafka and Debezium, besides the fact that Debezium supports multiple databases?

Comment: The biggest difference is durability: No connection = no message. When messages are a “nice to have”, pg_notify is an easy to use solution. But if you are relying on these messages, you need something else. Like Debezium or pgq